# 2 return values in a function depending on if statement? (JS)

Tags: javascript

I want to create a function that takes in an array. If the array is empty (or === 0) I want to return one string. If the array is not empty, I want to return a different string + remove+return first element of array. How do I accomplish this?

Sample

```
> function(ary) {
> if (ary.length === 0) {
>-return string-
>}
>else {return other string + ary.shift[0]}
>}
```

Comment: The code seems to be fine. What issues did you encounter?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @MaxZoom I did not get to the else under any circumstance, it just returned the first string.

Comment: See the documentation for [shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: @MaxZoom forgive my ignorance but I am an extreme beginner. If my if statement isn't true, my code still does not make it into my else. It just returns the string from the if statement.

Comment: @jsc42 Please see my post below

Comment: Tip: Insert effort in becoming familiar with the [F12 tools.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is your code with one `shift` correction:

```js
function check(ary) {
  if (ary.length === 0) {
    return "empty";
  } else {
    return "First was the " + ary.shift()
  }
}

console.log( check([]) );
console.log( check(['word', 'chaos', 'light']) );
```

Answer (score 1):

`shift` is a function that take no parameter. It should be called like this:

```
function(ary) {
    if (ary.length === 0) {
        return "string";
    }
    else {
        return "other string" + ary.shift();
    }
}
```

**Note** that the `else` could be removed. Just the return statment is enough since if the length of `ary` is 0 the code after `if` will never be reached (because of the `return` inside the `if` body), so the code after could be left unwrapped by the `else`. Like this:

```
function(ary) {
    if (ary.length === 0) // remove the braces as well since the `if` body is just one statement
        return "string";
    return "other string" + ary.shift(); // if `if`'s test is true this line will never be reached
}
```